# GEE area calculations default projection after taking median of an image collection

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, reduceregion

I am taking the area of the median image of 5 image layers of habitat suitability that I generating using random forest in GEE. I want to calculate the area of habitat in the median image was previously specifying the projection and crs transform as in the developer example:https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-pixelarea

Then I realized my area calculations were different when I input them into a different script because when I took the median of the image collection the projection changed to the default projection, WGS84 with 1-degree scale. Instead of specifying the image projection in the area calculation, should I only specify the scale of the image?

Here is my code:

```
var Present_HSI = ee.ImageCollection([HSI_2016, HSI_2017, HSI_2018, HSI_2019, HSI_2020, HSI_2021]); 

//Select the classification band and take the median 

var Present_HSI = Present_HSI.select(['classification']);

var Present_median = Present_HSI.median();

//Filter median image based on threshold that maximises sum of specificity and sensitivity 

var Present_habitat = Present_median.gt(0.42);

Map.addLayer(Present_habitat);

//median habitat area present in square kilometers 
// Create a pixel area image. Pixel values are square meters based on
// a given CRS and scale (or CRS transform).

var pixelArea = ee.Image.pixelArea();

var habitatpres = pixelArea.updateMask(Present_habitat); 

// Sum the area.

var areaPresent = habitatpres.reduceRegion({

  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),

  geometry: PNW,

  maxPixels: 1e10, 

  crs: Present_median.projection(),  // coordinate reference system

  crsTransform: Present_median.projection().getInfo().transform,  // grid alignment

});

// Fetch the summed area property from the resulting dictionary and convert
// square meters to square kilometers.

var squareMetersPres = areaPresent.getNumber('area');
var squareKilometersPres = squareMetersPres.divide(1e6);

print('Square kilometers area Present', squareKilometersPres);
```